# Assign value to html element using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, function

I have this function `getOrderNumber()` that I want to create a unique order number using the javascript `getTime()`. I need then the function `getOrderNumber()` to somehow assign a value to the html element. I tried a few iterations of what I have here which didn't work.

Any help would be appreciated.

```html
<form action="https://www.someurl/saocctest.cgi" method="post">

<!--get unique order number-->
<script>
function getOrderNumber() {
    var d = new Date();
    var n = d.getTime();
    form.elements("orderNumber").value=n;
}
</script>

<input type="hidden" name="orderNumber">
```

Comment: Seems like you need to do a bit more study. I'm not sure what you're really trying to accomplish here. What's calling your function? Where did the variable `form` come from? Maybe this will help: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_html.asp

Answer (score 1):

Set Id name to your HTML form

```
<form id="myForm" action="https://www.someurl/saocctest.cgi" method="post">
```

And then assign the value using this in your function

```
document.getElementById("myForm").elements[0].value = 'hello';
```

Or else add id/class to your input and the assign using

```
document.getElementById('id'); // Using Id
document.getElementsByClassName('class')[0]; // Using class
```

It will work

Demo : https://jsbin.com/molagu/2/edit?html,js,output

Comment: The old IE 'trick' that ``id`` values of DOM elements are variables in the Global scope is now an official W3C standard and supported by all Browsers, that means ``myForm`` is available as global so ``document.getElementById("myForm").elements``  is the same as ``myForm.elements``

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're after

```
<form id="myForm" action="https://www.someurl/saocctest.cgi" method="post">

<script>
function getOrderNumber() {
    var myForm = document.getElementById('myForm'); 
    var d = new Date();
    var n = d.getTime();
    myForm.elements[0].value = n;
}
</script>

<input type="hidden" name="orderNumber">
```

Notice you could probably just give the input an id and change the value that way e.g.

```
<input type="hidden" name="orderNumber" id="myOrderNumber">
```

then

```
document.getElementById('myOrderNumber').value = n;
```

Also note when using `document.getElementById("myForm").elements[0].value = 'hello';`as per other answers here that you are targeting the first element within the form, if you ever add another element above this then you will update the wrong item value.

Safest option as I've mentioned would be to place an id on the input itself then target that.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript doesn't create global references of HTML page elements in this way. In modern browsers, if you've a element with specific identifier, you can directly get it from its id in the global object.

For example

```
<div id="my-id"></div>
```

JS

```js
alert(this['my-id'])
```

Where `this`, `window`, if you're not in strict mode and if you're in a global scope.

Actually, if you want a cross-browser equivalent way to get the `form` element,

```
document.getElementsByTagName('form')[0]
```

Every DOM element has methods like `getElementsByTagName`, `getElementsByClassName`, (these return a `HTMLCollection`, looks like a array, but it's not) ...

The `document` is the one object that contains the `getElementById` method, which returns the first element with specific identifier.

Also, if you want to get your form elements, use the methods I quoted, or simply index the form reference with the `'name'` attribute of the specific child. It's cross-browser to use `HTMLElement().getElementsByTagName`, etc.

---

Only input elements has the `value` property. You can change the `innerHTML` or `innerText` instead (they're getters/setters);